# Is it mandatory to name view and action mehod same in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view name EmployeeForm.cshtml and inside EmployeeController I have two action method MyView() and RandomView(). MyView() returns object of Employee Model while RandomView() method returns the object of EmployeeViewModel.

But the URl request goes as like: http://localhost:port/Employee/EmployeeForm i.e. MVC expects an EmployeeForm() method inside EmployeeController.

How can i correct this error ?

Comment: May be the routing definition maps the request to `EmployeeForm` action to one of the actions you have in the controller. Check the route registrations /attribute routes on the methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it's not.

You view form should point to the name desired, whatever it's the current *MyView()* or another custom name by decorating the controller action with attribute.

No matter what you choose, the view form must match the action name(or attribute name).

```
[ActionName("EmployeeForm")]
public ActionResult MyView()
{
    // You code here
    return View(); // Will use MyView page
    return View("SomeViewName"); // Will use SomeViewName page
}
```

Concerning View page, this is almost not related. You can set the controller action to return whatever View page you want using `View("SomeViewName", myModel)`.

**Note:** When using BeginForm without passing the desired action, it will use the current View file page as the target form Url action name.

Answer (score 0):

No You don't have to use same name view and action.

code:

```
public ActionResult EmployeForm()
{
    return ViewResult("AnotherViewName");
}
```